# I want to incorporate continuous (hands free) voice command recognition in my app for home automation

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, recognizer-intent

I have created a simple android app for controlling a relay connected to my Raspberry Pi. I have used buttons as well as basic voice recognition to trigger those buttons and switch on/off the corresponding relay channel.

As of now the voice recognition part is handled by a RecognizerIntent, wherein I need to press a button on my app to open a Google voice prompt which listens to my voice command and activates/deactivates the corresponding button which controls the relay switches.

I want to do the same with **continuous voice recognition which allows the app to continuously listen to my commands without the user having to press a button on the app, hence allowing hands-free operation.**

Here is my existing code, a very simple means of voice recognition which will allow me to switch on and off the buttons for various devices connected to the relay:

```
public void micclick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.mic)
        {promptSpeechInput();}
}

private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent i= new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speak!");
    try{
        startActivityForResult(i,100);

    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry your device doesn't support",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);
    String voicetxt;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && i != null) {
                ArrayList<String> result2 = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                voicetxt = result2.get(0);
                if (voicetxt.equals("fan on")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton1.setChecked(true);
                    result.append("Fan: ").append(toggleButton1.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber="a";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("fan of")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton1.setChecked(false);
                    result.append("Fan: ").append(toggleButton1.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "a_off";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("light on")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton2.setChecked(true);
                    result.append("Light: ").append(toggleButton2.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "b";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("light off")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton2.setChecked(false);
                    result.append("Light: ").append(toggleButton2.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "b_off";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("air conditioner on")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton3.setChecked(true);
                    result.append("AC: ").append(toggleButton3.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "c";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("air conditioner of")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton3.setChecked(false);
                    result.append("AC: ").append(toggleButton3.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "c_off";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("heater on")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton4.setChecked(true);
                    result.append("Heater: ").append(toggleButton4.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "d";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (voicetxt.equals("heater off")) {
                    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                    toggleButton4.setChecked(false);
                    result.append("Heater: ").append(toggleButton4.getText());
                    sc.onRelayNumber = "d_off";
                    new Thread(sc).start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the same functionality without having to press the button. Please note that I am new to Android app development. If possible, please be descriptive in the usage of external libraries, if they are required because I don't think continuous recognition is possible with Google's RecognizerIntent. I have speculated that I might need to include libraries like **CMUSphinx**, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 5):

There are several things you can do for continuous recognition / dictation mode. You can use the google speech recognition from the android itself, it's not recommended for continuous recognition (as stated on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)

> The implementation of this API is likely to stream audio to remote
>   servers to perform speech recognition. As such this API is not
>   intended to be used for continuous recognition, which would consume a
>   significant amount of battery and bandwidth.

But if you really need it, you can do a workaround by creating your own class and inherit IRecognitionListener. (I wrote this on xamarin-android, the syntax is very similar to native android)

```
public class CustomRecognizer : Java.Lang.Object, IRecognitionListener, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{
    private SpeechRecognizer _speech;

    private Intent _speechIntent;


    public string Words;


    public CustomRecognizer(Context _context)
    {
        this._context = _context;
        Words = "";
        _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
        _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
        _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech, RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000); 
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
    }

    void startover()
    {
        _speech.Destroy();
        _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
        _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
        _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
        _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
    StartListening();
    }
    public void StartListening()
    {
        _speech.StartListening(_speechIntent);
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        _speech.StopListening();
    }

    public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
    {

    }

    public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
    }

    public void OnEndOfSpeech()
    {

    }

    public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
    {
        Words = error.ToString();
        startover();
    }

    public void OnEvent(int eventType, Bundle @params)
    {
    }

    public void OnPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {
    }

    public void OnReadyForSpeech(Bundle @params)
    {
    }

    public void OnResults(Bundle results)
    {

        var matches = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
        if (matches == null)
            Words = "Null";
        else
            if (matches.Count != 0)
            Words = matches[0];
        else
            Words = "";

        //do anything you want for the result
        }
        startover();
    }

    public void OnRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {

    }

    public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status)
    {
        if (status == OperationResult.Error)
            txtspeech.SetLanguage(Java.Util.Locale.Default);
    }


}
```

**To Call it on the activity :**

```
void StartRecording()
    {
        string rec = PackageManager.FeatureMicrophone;

        if (rec != "android.hardware.microphone")
        {
            // no microphone, no recording. Disable the button and output an alert
            Toast.MakeText(this, "NO MICROPHONE", ToastLength.Short);
        }
        else
        {

            //you can pass any object you want to connect to your recognizer here (I am passing the activity)
            CustomRecognizer voice = new CustomRecognizer(this);
            voice.StartListening();

        }
    }
```

**Don't forget to request permission to use microphone!**

Explanation :

-This will remove the annoying "click to start recording"

-This will always record the moment you call StartListening() and never stops because I always call startover() or StartListening() everytime it finished recording

-This is a pretty bad workaround since the moment it process your recording, the recorder won't get any sound input until it called StartListening() (There are no workaround for this)

-Google recognition is not really good for voice command since the language model is "[lang] sentences", so you can't limit the word, and google will always try to make a "good sentence" as a result.

For better result and UX, I really suggest you use Google Cloud API (but it must be online, and costly), the second suggestion is CMUSphinx / PocketSphinx, it is open source, can do offline mode, but you have to do all things manually

PocketSphinx advantage :

1. You can Create your own dictionary
2. Offline mode compatible
3. You can do your own training for accoustic model (phonetic, etc), so you can configure it depends on your environment and pronounciation
4. You can get real-time result by accessing "PartialResult"

PocketSphinx disadvantage : You have to do all things manually, from setting up your accoustic model, dictionary, language model, threshold, etc. (overkill if you want something simple).

Comment: In my case I want to stop loading Google speak popup and run the listener continuously on button click.How can I do that without using a speechrecognizer?

Answer (score 0):

You could make it respond to "house, (pause) turn on lights" by using the following method (although it will respond to other words not just 'house'):

You could continuously record audio (but not into file) using AudioRecord class until raw recording data tells you that you detected some volume threshold (such as when saying "house"). When you detect this threshold you continue to record until there's at least 0.5seconds of silence. At that point, you stop recording and immediately call speechRecognizer.StartListening function. Then the user will hear the beep and when he hears the beep, he can say "turn on lights".

Something like this should therefore achieve the desired functionality, although it's not perfect.

Best regards.